# How to get the pages created by user after login and share some text on those with Android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

actually I'm not posting a bug but I have question with current sdk (android).
is it possible to get all the pages which are crated by the user after Login to Facebook and I want to share some text on the page which I select ? 
I mean is there any other way to do this thing in android? like with Graph API, or with SDK?

Comment: can you please explain what is your app all about and which pages are you talking about? Please be specific.

Comment: for example i have account on fb and i have created 4 pages on facebook and when i login to facebook via sdk  ,i want to show all those 4 pages i created in Listview and when i select one of them i want to share some text on selected page. is it possible with current sdk?

Comment: What do you mean by "Facebook pages" - they have status updates, photos and messages. They do not have "pages" in their API. Do you mean a user FB "wall" or something like that?

Comment: Of course this is possible via API. You will need to get `manage_pages` permission from the user to get a list of the pages they admin, and to get a page access token to make the post (assuming you want to post “as” the page, rather than as the user).

Comment: thanks @CBroe, that helps me allot, but after getting manage_pages permissions from user, is there any code to list the pages I admin in Facebook ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens